# pimpl idiom using anonymous-namespace structure: is this safe?

Tags: c++, namespaces, pimpl-idiom, incomplete-type

A teammate of mine regularly uses a variation on pimpl, which he does like this:

Foo.h:

```
namespace { struct Impl; }

class Foo
{
public:
  Foo();
  ~Foo();

  void Bar(int n);
  /* ... */

private:
  std::unique_ptr<Impl> _impl;
};
```

What's happening here is that he's forward-declaring the implementation class to be in the anonymous namespace. Then he'll define the `Impl` class within Foo.cpp .

So the definition of the structure `::Impl` will be available to `Foo.cpp`'s translation unit. Other code include `Foo.h` will raise a warning, because they obviously can't access `::Impl` defined in `Foo.cpp`. But then, we don't need them to - it's a class meant to be used in `Foo.cpp` only; we don't *want* it visible or known elsewhere.

And while we can certainly have a situation where on `.cpp` file is including multiple headers, each declaring their own `::Impl` structures, these don't actually clash, because the structures are never used outside  their respective translation units.

**tl;dr:** This looks weird, raises warnings, and looks as though it can cause clashes, but seems to actually work.

---

All that being said, I'm not comfortable with having something that raises warnings baked so deeply into our code (the more header files this is in, the harder it's going to be to take out.) It's also just a *ton* of warnings.

My teammate stands by this because it's simple, keeps the code definitions simple, and lets us use the short, consistent classname `Impl` across all our code.

I'm not a stickler for coding conventions; if this is good practice for our use-case, I don't mind. But I would like to feel comfortable that this is safe and maintainable, and isn't going to blow up in our faces at some point.

Comment: The point is, I *think*, that there is no `::Impl`. Using `::Impl` tries to access the symbol `Impl` in the *global* namespace, but it's not in the global namespace. Another common way is to make the `Impl` structure a private member of the class itself.

Comment: If this occurs in a header file that is used by multiple translation units, then I think it is an ODR violation.  Each anonymous namespace is different in each translation unit, therefore class Foo will not have a consistent definition across all translation units.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23653494/951890

Comment: @VaughnCato : The inconsistency seems to be at the level of *which class* the _impl pointer is pointing to, which can only be accessed from within Foo's own implementation. Is that an actual ODR violation?

Comment: @Ziv: The inconsistency is in the name "Impl", which either means some_anonymous_namespace1::Impl or some_anonymous_namespace2::Impl depending on which translation unit you are in, but this is an ODR violation, since all names must have the same meaning in all translation units.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : Are you suggesting making `Impl` a nested class/structure? I thought you [can't forward-declare a nested class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021793/how-do-i-forward-declare-an-inner-class)  (and if you can't forward-declare it, it's no use for pimpl).

Comment: @VaughnCato : I can definitely see how this looks like a bad practice and an ambiguous definition. I think my teammate is dismissing this since the conflicting definition is merely the pointer *type* - which doesn't affect size, and shouldn't (?) affect behavior, since only `Foo.cpp` can actually access the pointer. But I agree, any discrepancy seems dangerous to play with.

Comment: @Ziv Huh, [sure you can](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a75157224bfed2eb)

Comment: @Ziv You need to do the forward declaration *inside* the class. E.g. `class Foo { struct Impl; public: ... };`

Comment: Thanks to you all. I've learned many helpful things :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The class `Foo` violates the ODR.  Each cpp file thinks its unique ptr contains a different type.

ODR violation makes your program ill formed, no diagnostic required.

Your program may work, but its behaviour is completely unspecified by the C++ standard.

The practical issue that could result is the compiler may change under your feet, and the current undefined behaviour ("it seems to work") will change to something else ("casts fail unexpectedly", "corrupt type tables", "linker fails to link", "compiler proves class is can never be used outside of its implemented translation unit, and erases all code in your functions as if they ran it would be UB.") as examples, but there is no bound to how insane it could get.

There is sometimes a benefit to doing UB, worth the risk.  I see zero benefit here.

Create a `namespace FooImpl` or `Foo_details` and stuff the `Impl` in there.